# Android toolbar inside a tab menu retrieval

Tags: java, android, menu, fragment, toolbar

How do I get a menu for my toolbar inside a fragment (tab)? I'm relatively new to android and java.

Here's the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your Toolbar to your Activity and use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your fragment to inflate the menu you need and add `setHaOptionsMenu(true)` in the `onCreate()` of your fragment.